# Saving a session on Passport js

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, web, passport.js

```
app.use(session({
    name: 'codeial',
    // TODO change the secret before deployment in production mode
    secret: 'blah blah',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    resave: false,
    cookie: {
        maxAge: (1000 * 60 * 100)
    },
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: db,
        autoRemove: 'disabled'
    },function(err){
        console.log(err || 'connect-mongodb setup ok');
    })
}));
```

The above code is giving me error:

> throw new Error('Cannot init client. Please provide correct options');

Answer (score 0):

`mongooseConnection: db` is the culprit. Assuming you use connect-mongo, there is no such option called `mongooseConnection`.

See `ConnectMongoOptions` declaration here: https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo/blob/master/src/lib/MongoStore.ts